# ASP.NET Repeater issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization, repeater

I'm a new to .NET development and I have run into an issue with some data not showing up in my repeater.

I have an XML file that I am deserializing and using a repeater to display that data. My issue is that the Location and Salary data are not showing up, every other XML element is.

I am not sure how to access the JobLocations class and display Salary and Location.

.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Jobs>   
  <Job Category="Administration" Title="Senior Human Resource Coordinator">
    <Description>
      <![CDATA[ Long description of the job goes here. ]]>
    </Description>
    <ShortDescription>
      <![CDATA[ Short description of the job goes here.  ]]>
    </ShortDescription>
    <JobLocations>
      <Location Salary="$50000">Toronto</Location>
      <Location Salary="£35000">London</Location>
    </JobLocations>
    <Benefits>Drug, Dental, Optical and Extended Healthcare Benefits</Benefits>
    <Jobtype>Full-Time</Jobtype>
  </Job>
</Job>
```

.cs

```
[Serializable]
public class Job
{        
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Category { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("JobLocations")]
    public List<JobLocations> JobLocation { get; set; }

    public string Benefits { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string Jobtype { get; set; }                


    public class JobLocations
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Salary")]
        public string Salary { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public string Location { get; set; }
    }

    public static List<Job> Load( string path )
    {
        return SerializerSupport.DeserializeList<Job>(System.IO.Path.Combine( path, "jobs.xml" ) );
    }
```

.aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Job" runat="server" ItemType="Job" SelectMethod="JobGrid_GetData">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="flex-item">
            <div>Title: <%#Item.Title%></div>
            <div>S.Desc: <%#Item.ShortDescription%></div>
            <div>Location: ??? </div>
            <div>Salary: ??? </div>
            <div>Category: <%#Item.Category%></div>
            <div>Jobtype: <%#Item.Jobtype%></div>
            <div>Benefits: <%#Item.Benefits%></div>  
            <div>Desc: <%#Item.Description%></div>
          </div>  
        </ItemTemplate>        
    </asp:Repeater>
```

.aspx.cs

```
public partial class JobCategories : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<Job> JobGrid_GetData()
    {
        return DataCache.Instance.Jobs;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Job> Jobs_GetData()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Job> JobGrid_DistinctCategories()
    {
        return DataCache.Instance.Jobs.GroupBy(p => p.Category).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your location and salary data aren't stored directly in the `Job`. They're stored in the `JobLocation` property of `Job`, which is a collection object. That's why you can't access them like `<%#Item.Salary%></div>`, because there's multiple salaries/locations.

Depending on how you want to display the data, you may need to have a nested repeater or other control that displays the salary.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Job" runat="server" ItemType="Job" SelectMethod="JobGrid_GetData">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="flex-item">
            <div>Title: <%#Item.Title%></div>
            <div>S.Desc: <%#Item.ShortDescription%></div>
            <div>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ItemType="JobLocations" DataSource="<%# Item.JobLocation %>">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div>Location: <%#Item.Location%> </div>
                        <div>Salary: <%#Item.Salary%> </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
            <div>Category: <%#Item.Category%></div>
            <div>Jobtype: <%#Item.Jobtype%></div>
            <div>Benefits: <%#Item.Benefits%></div>  
            <div>Desc: <%#Item.Description%></div>
          </div>  
        </ItemTemplate>        
    </asp:Repeater>
```

---

An alternative way of doing this is a foreach loop, but those end up looking a little ugly with all the `<%` markup scattered everywhere. If you're not stuck on Web Forms, then switching to [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) so you can use [Razor markup](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c) would be an improvement.

```
foreach(var job in jobs)
{
    <div>Title: @job.Title</div>
    <div>S.Desc: @job.ShortDescription</div>
    ...etc...
    foreach(var jobLocation in job.JobLocation)
    {
        <div>Location: @jobLocation.Location</div>
        <div>Salary: @jobLocation.Salary</div>
    }
    <div>Category: @job.Category</div>
    ...etc...
}
```

---

Your `JobLocations` class should be renamed `JobLocation` and your `Job.JobLocation` property should be renamed `Job.JobLocations` in keeping with normal C# conventions. That's because the property represents a collection of job locations, so it makes sense to pluralize the name. However, the class represents a single instance so don't pluralize the name.

Comment: Yes, another repeater should work so it can cycle through them all for that one job. When there are multiple values you have to loop through them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance Mason and Devin. Your answers put me on the right track in solving my programming issue. Are there any beginner learning resources you would recommend for MVC and/or Razor?

Comment: @danslik Well I provided two links in my answer. Then there's the usual places to look, such as MSDN, Pluralsight, [Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC), and YouTube.